# MATLAB Insert matrix into 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a 1437X159X1251 large matrix and I want to insert a 1437x159 matrix into the middle of the larger matrix, making the large matrix 1437x159x1252 large. How would I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For horizontal or vertial concatenation of matrices/vectors `A` and `B`, you can use

```
% vertical 
[A; B]; 

% horizontal 
[A, B];  % comma is optional:
[A  B];
```

There is no such notation for the *third* dimension. You'll have to use the generalized  concatenation in *arbitrary* dimension `cat()`:

```
% Example matrices
A = rand(1437, 159, 1251);
B = rand(1437, 159); 

% Insertion point
N = 384;

% How to do it
A = cat(3, A(:,:,1:N), B, A(:,:,N+1:end));
```

Comment: Note: last line should be `A = cat(3, A(:,:,1:N), B, A(:,:,N+1:end));` - otherwise you miss a slice!

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was trying to fix after trying out the code.